# Saving blocks of code in variables

Tags: java, eclipse, block

In Objective C you have a function blocks.
You can save blocks of code in a variable and pass them as parameters.

```
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // Enumerating all the objects of an array
}];
```

In my game I have a `MenuScene` with `MenuSceneItem`s.
In this case I would want to pass the code they should execute if they have been clicked.
This would eliminate the need of a switch statement.

Is there a way to to is there a way to do this or something similar in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can't have anonymous function blocks you need to use an anonymous class:

```
menuScene.executeWhenClicked(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: To be clear, that's an anonymous class, not an anonymous function

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like straightforward polymorphism e.g.

```
public interface Action {
   void doSomethingWhenPressed();
}
```

and just implement an object that implements the above interface. Pass that as an argument.

You'd likely do this using an *anonymous* class e.g.

```
// this method takes an 'Action' as an argument
passToMethod(new Action() {
   public void doSomethingWhenPressed() {
      System.out.println("Pressed!");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In java, you create an object (it doesn't have to have an explicit class type) that extends Runnable, and put the block of code in the `run` method.  Like so

```
    Runnable myDelayedBlockOfCode = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doA();
            doB();
            doC();
        }
    };
```

If working with a framework, look closer for a framework specific interface that allows you to place such blocks of code into whatever the framework will call.